# r-contiguous matching, MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, pattern-matching

I want to compare these two strings by r-contiguous matching rule.
So in this example if we set r as 6 then it will return true for the first example and false for the second example.

Example 1:

```
A='ABCDEFGHIJKLM'
B='XYZ0123EFGHIJAB'
return true (since it they both have 6 contiguous match 'EFGHIJ')
```

Example 2:

```
A='ABCDEFGHJKLM'
B='XYZ0123EFGHAB'
return false (since they both have only 4 contiguous match 'EFGH')
```

What is the fastest way in MATLAB since my data is huge? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Case : Input strings with unique characters**

Here's one approach with [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) & [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html)  -

```
matches = ismember(A,B) %// OR any(bsxfun(@eq,A,B.'),1)
matches_ext = [0 matches 0]

starts = strfind(matches_ext,[0 1])
stops = strfind(matches_ext,[1 0])    
interval_lens = stops - starts

out = any(interval_lens >= r)
```

Here's another with [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) & [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) instead of `strfind` -

```
matches = ismember(A,B) %// OR any(bsxfun(@eq,A,B.'),1)
matches_ext = [0 matches 0]

df = diff(matches_ext)
interval_lens = find(df == -1) - find(df == 1)

out = any(interval_lens >= r)
```

Here's another with [`1D convolution`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) -

```
matches = ismember(A,B) %// OR any(bsxfun(@eq,A,B.'),1)
out = any(conv(double(matches),ones(1,r)) == r)
```

---

**Case : Input strings with non-unique characters**

Here's one approach using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
matches = bsxfun(@eq,A,B.');  %//'
intv = (0:r-1)*(size(matches,1)+1)+1
idx = find(matches)
idx = idx(idx <= max(idx) - max(intv))
out = any(all(matches(bsxfun(@plus,idx,intv)),2))
```

Comment: I think there is a problem inside of the logic of the program. As I mention having "contiguous match" is important ! they should be similar in R continuous cases.
Example 2 has 6 matches BUT they are not continuous. Can you help me with a solution which find continuous similarities?

Comment: @HaHacker That's why the codes with the second example return `False/0`, doesn't it, which is the expected output for that case?

Comment: Yes, But why when I use this example it gives me true !
A='1010101010101010'
B='11110000000'
R=5

Comment: @HaHacker Ah I see. Well the listed codes assumed unique characters in the strings, as were the cases in the samples of the question.

Comment: Any way thanks for the help :) I hope someone help me to figure a fast way to do that.

Comment: Now it works for non-unique characters ! Thanks a lot.