# Fast r-contiguous matching (based on location similarities)

Tags: performance, matlab, pattern-matching

Assume that we have 2 equal size binary.

```
A=101011110000
B=000010101111
```

How can we check their "R" contiguous matching  based on similar location?

For example if we set r=4 then the result will be false since there is no 4 contiguous similarities of locations. Both strings have 0000 or 1111 or 1010 but they are not in similar location .

However if we set :

```
A=1010111101111
B=1100101011111
```

The result will be true since the last 4 char (R) in both strings are equal to "1111".

What is the fastest way to do that. I found a fast solution in :
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/257051-fast-r-contiguous-matching

```
bin = 2.^(0:r - 1);
A2 = filter(bin, 1, A == '1');
B2 = filter(bin, 1, B == '1');
bool = any(ismember(A2(r:end), B2(r:end))); % need to trim first r-1 entries
```

But in this solution checking similarities is not based on location.

Comment: How important is performance? You'd like it fast? or it's super important to be fast?

Comment: See if [`r-contiguous matching, MATLAB`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871672/r-contiguous-matching-matlab) helps.

Comment: If you check the link in mathworks you will see two solutions, one works in 5.936 sec the other in 0.002 sec. My original string is 160 bits and I need to compare it with 50,000 strings (160 bits). So I need something fast enough.

Comment: Divakar, the solution will not find the similarities based on the location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC, you could simply use [`convolution`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html), like so -

```
any(conv(double(A==B),ones(r,1))>=r)
```

---

**Sample runs**

Run #1 :

```
A =
101011110000
B =
000010101111
r =
     4
out =
     0
```

Run #2 :

```
A =
1010111101111
B =
1100101011111
r =
     4
out =
     1
```

Comment: what is the type of A and B? I get wrong answer on my machine.

Comment: @Divakar, thanks, it is working
Ha Hacker, It is char array.