# Detect contiguous numbers - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, duplicates

I coded a program that create some bunch of binary numbers like this:

```
out = [0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0];
```

I want check existence of nine `1` digit together in above `out`, for example when we have this in our output:

```
out_2 = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
```

or

```
out_3 = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0];
```

`condition` variable should be set to `1`. We don't know exact position of start of ones in `out`variable. It is random. I only want find existence of duplicate ones values in above variable (one occurrence or more).

**PS.**

We are searching for a general answer to find other duplicate numbers (not only 1 here and not only for binary data. this is just an example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`convolution`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) to solve such r-contiguous detection cases.

**Case #1 :** To find contiguous `1s` in a binary array -

```
check = any(conv(double(input_arr),ones(r,1))>=r)
```

Sample run -

```
input_arr =
     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
r =
     9
check =
     1
```

**Case #2 :** For detecting any number as contiguous, you could modify it a bit, like so -

```
check = any(conv(double(diff(input_arr)==0),ones(1,r-1))>=r-1)
```

Sample run -

```
input_arr =
     3     5     2     4     4     4     5     5     2     2
r =
     3
check =
     1
```

To save Stackoverflow from further duplicates, also feel free to look into related problems -

1. [`Fast r-contiguous matching (based on location similarities).`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34153090/fast-r-contiguous-matching-based-on-location-similarities)
2. [`r-contiguous matching, MATLAB.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871672/r-contiguous-matching-matlab)

Comment: Thank you for answer. If we don't know the duplicate number (the data is not binary- here the duplicate number is 1) and we only want find 9 duplicate numbers together? I'm searching for a more general answer here.

Comment: @user2991243 That changes a lot of things here. Consider posting that as a separate question?

Comment: @user2991243 Edited my solution. And don't worry about that. I might have to edit the question later on to reflect the new requirements *properly*.